# Relationships in Postmaster Parcel

Tags: postmaster

Is it possible to use the new EE 2.6 native relationships in parcels.  I cant seem to get it to work... tried a few different syntax styles?

```
Your application for {parcel:application_related_fair}{application_related_fair:title}{/parcel:application_related_fair}has been submitted and will be reviewed shortly.

Your application for {parcel:application_related_fair}{parcel:application_related_fair:title}{/parcel:application_related_fair}has been submitted and will be reviewed shortly.

Your application for {parcel:application_related_fair}{title}{/parcel:application_related_fair}has been submitted and will be reviewed shortly.

Your application for {parcel:application_related_fair:title} has been submitted and will be reviewed shortly.
```

none of these seem to work?

Comment: I should also note i tried the suggest 
{exp:channel:entries inside a parsel but thats not parsing at all?

Comment: I think it would be best if you emailed support@objectivehtml.com so I can help you. Something isn't correct on your end somewhere, because this stuff should definitely work. I need to ask some questions before I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might have the same question:

The Answer is, yes you can. Just put your regular {exp:channel:entries} code in either the message or subject and it renders like in any other template. Example:

{exp:channel:entries channel="your_channel" limit="1"}
Your message {relationship_field}{relationship_field:your_field_that_you_need}{/relationship_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Since the question was older, it might be that the reasons it works is that I am on a newer version (EE 2.9.2 and Postmaster 1.5)

If not, I am glad to help